# how to link arm math library to compile for the stm32f4

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to calculate FFT on the stm32f4

The first errors I got were:

```
/home/mennesker/Workspace/stm/STM-mainopdracht2/main.c:111: undefined reference to `arm_cfft_radix4_init_f32'
/home/mennesker/Workspace/stm/STM-mainopdracht2/main.c:114: undefined reference to `arm_cfft_radix4_f32'
/home/mennesker/Workspace/stm/STM-mainopdracht2/main.c:117: undefined reference to `arm_cmplx_mag_f32'
/home/mennesker/Workspace/stm/STM-mainopdracht2/main.c:120: undefined reference to `arm_max_f32'
```

So I Thought I need to link the library because in the include files there are only .h files.

The libraries are in the same root folder so,
 the .h files (arm_math.h and core_cm4.h) are in the folder:

```
/home/mennesker/Workspace/stm/STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0/Libraries/CMSIS/Include/
```

The library arm_cortexM4b_math.lib is in folder:

```
/home/mennesker/Workspace/stm/STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0/Libraries/CMSIS/Lib/ARM/
```

I tried many different variantions of paths where to put the library to link with using `-l arm_cortexM4b_math.lib` as linker option or `-l <path to file> /arm_cortexM4b_math.lib`

But I still get the error:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -larm_cortexM4b_math.lib
```

I don't know where the linker looks and how this linking really works

Comment: Use -L to set the library search path, -l to specify a library name

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried that with the different cases of specifiing where the file is but than it gives an ld error and than the same undefined references